# Doctrine: How to choose TargetEntity based on Entity Columns?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this kind of problem that I 'd like to solve with Doctrine, but Im a bit confused.

Let me explain the project. There is a Site, and a Contact. Each contact belongs to ONE site.
Each Contact can create a Request related to a specific Site ( filling different forms): each request is totally different from one site to another one, so I have  as many Request Tables as Site. Assume I have 2 Site: X and Y.
Each Request will have 0 or N Responses; as for Request, Response is based on Site and will have different tables.

Recap: 2 Sites: X and Y. Table Summary: site, contact, requestX, requestY, responseX, responseY.

I'd like to create an Inheritance association "JOINED" so that, based on the value of contact.site_id, I will get RequestX object or RequestY object.
Example:

```
$contact->getRequest() >> Collection of RequestX if site_id  of contact = X
$contact->getRequest() >> Collection of RequestY if site_id  of contact = Y
```

Is there a way to get this with Inheritance Mapping? or is simpler to create ContactX with mapped RequestX, etc etc ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Class inheritance should work. Just think of the discr column as site id

Comment: show us what you already tried so we can undrestand and help you